# Using column aliases in Sales Order Grid field

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to add two fields (`Shipping Postcode` and `Billing Postcod`) to Magento 1.7CE's backend Sales grid.

I'm doing this by overriding `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::setCollection(...)` to join the table with `sales/order_address`.

```
public function setCollection($collection){
    parent::setCollection($collection);
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('address_shipping' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
        'main_table.entity_id = address_shipping.parent_id AND address_shipping.address_type = "shipping"',
        array('postcode')
    );
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('address_billing' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
        'main_table.entity_id = address_billing.parent_id AND address_billing.address_type = "billing"',
        array('postcode')
    );
}
```

And `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareColumns(...)` to add the columns to Sales Grid.

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){
    $this->addColumn('shipping_postcode', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
        'index' => 'postcode',
    ));
    $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Postcode'),
        'index' => 'postcode',
    ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

The issue is that both times I need to select `postcode` field from `sales/order_address` table which results in SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'postcode' in order clause is ambiguous
```

I have tried to use MySQL's `AS` alias to differentiate between two postcodes, by modifying `setCollection(...)` to pass `array('shipping_postcode'=>'postcode')` and `array('billing_postcode'=>'postcode')` as well as changing `_prepareColumns(...)` to say `'index' => 'shipping_postcode'` and `'index' => 'billing_postcode'`. This resulted in another SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shipping_postcode' in 'where clause'
```

How can I achieve having both columns in the Sales Grid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

let try this first code

```
public function setCollection($collection){
    parent::setCollection($collection);
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('address_shipping' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
        'main_table.entity_id = address_shipping.parent_id AND address_shipping.address_type = "shipping"',
        array('address_shipping.postcode as shippingpostcode')
    );

    $collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('address_billing' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
        'main_table.entity_id = address_billing.parent_id AND address_billing.address_type = "billing"',
        array('address_billing.postcode as billingpostcode')
    );
}
```

Second `_prepareColumns()` is here,

```
protected function _prepareColumns(){
     $this->addColumn('shippingpostcode', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
        'index' => 'shippingpostcode',
        'filter_index' => 'address_shipping.postcode'
     ));

    $this->addColumn('billingpostcode', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Postcode'),
        'index' => 'billingpostcode',
        'filter_index' => 'address_billing.postcode'  
    ));

return parent::_prepareColumns();

}
```

if you want to know more about `'filter_index'`, comment in/out in this, then try sorting in your grid for post code column. You will see different result. If you remove `filter_index`, error in sorting.

Comment: Happy for help and Welcome

Answer (score 3):

Before `return parent::_prepareCollection();` 
You should create a join:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),
        'main_table.entity_id = billing.parent_id AND billing.address_type="billing"',array('billing.postcode AS bp'));
```

And in the method _prepareColumns paste:

```
$this->addColumn('bp', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Postcode'),
            'index' => 'bp',
            'width' => '60px',
            'filter_index'  => 'billing.postcode'
        ));
```